# removing elements in a vector that contain pure numbers in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that has character elements like

`"2-CONTROL", "DAN-COLOR", "3M", "DIPLOMVEJ 373", "ABE 34 HUN"`

I'd like to filter out the elements the elements that have independent numbers within the string. If the number is attached to alphabets or hyphen, then it should not be filtered.

The above vector will give the below result after filtering.

```
"2-CONTROL", "DAN-COLOR", "3M"
```

I have tried using `"\\b\\d+\\b"` within a grepl but it also filters out `"2-CONTROL"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Replace each character that is not a digit and not whitespace with X and then use your regular expression:

```
pat <- "\\b\\d+\\b" # from question

x[!grepl(pat, gsub("[^[:space:][:digit:]]", "X", x))]
## [1] "2-CONTROL" "DAN-COLOR" "3M"
```

**2)** Another possibility is to split on whitespace and reject any containing an element of all digits.

```
x[sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), function(x) !any(grepl("^\\d+$", x)))]
## [1] "2-CONTROL" "DAN-COLOR" "3M"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `tidyverse` approach, use `stringr::str_detect()`:

```
library(stringr)

strings <- c("2-CONTROL", "DAN-COLOR", "3M", "DIPLOMVEJ 373", "ABE 34 HUN")
pattern <- " \\d+ ?" # match free-standing integers

strings[!str_detect(strings, pattern)]
# [1] "2-CONTROL" "DAN-COLOR" "3M"
```

Answer (score -1):

Negation logic seems to work:

```
regexp <- "\\d{2,}"

x <- c("2-CONTROL", "DAN-COLOR", "3M", "DIPLOMVEJ 373", "ABE 34 HUN")
res <- x[!grepl(regexp, x)]
res
# "2-CONTROL" "DAN-COLOR" "3M"
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run the first line     Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\d"    

Sorry if the comment is too dumb but I am new to R

Comment: the `\` escape was missing. not sure why it seemed to work when I tried it the first time.